# Is it possible for a spy to send 100 Peta Byte of secret data securely online?

Tags: security, data

Suppose a spy in an enemy country has got access to 100 or more Peta Byte of top secret data. He wants to pass on the data to his headquarters. But he also wants to make sure that at no cost the data should fall in the hands of any third party.

Is it possible for the spy to send data securely online? Or is it necessary for him to physically transport the storage device?

Comment: He can send it over an IP-SEC tunnel (but I will report this)

Comment: Securely? Yes. Covertly? To some degree, *maybe*. However, for the decades it would take to move that volume of data, one should expect it to be detected. Someone is going to notice 25,000 hard drives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking if data can be encrypted so that only authorized people can read it?  If so, the answer is yes -- we do it all the time.  You're doing it right now when you view this web page using SSL.  There are a couple of caveats, of course.  You need to use a strong encryption algorithm, and you need to have a sufficiently long key to prevent a brute-force attack.  You also have to insure that the sender and receiver have exchanged keys and that no one else has them.

If you're asking if the spy can send 100Pb of data and not be detected, that's an entirely different issue.  It depends on how well the network is monitored, and how much that traffic differs from normal traffic.  The "enemy" may not be able to read the data, but if they detect that someone is sending a large amount of encrypted traffic to a "foreign" country, it may be detrimental to the health of the spy.

Comment: 100 PB over a gigabit link would require 26 years to send... Chances are you're going to be discovered by then - or in retirement.

Comment: @zac67 Or your enemy will have become your ally :)

Comment: Yes! Excellent point!